# Python pathlib glob function fails on WindowsError: [123]?

Tags: python, unicode, windowserror

I've written the following python function that returns a python list of File Geodatabase Paths. Please note that `input_folder` is a raw string and contains no unicode characters.

```
try:
    gdbs = list(Path(input_folder).glob('**/*.gdb'))
    for gdb in gdbs:
        print(gdb)
except WindowsError, e:
    print("error")
```

The problem that I'm having is that `pathlib` `glob` method is failing when it encounters unicode characters in the path of files in the directory.

I tried the following but it still fails, which I assume is because I'm not converting the paths the `glob` generator is coming across.

```
try:
    gdbs = list(Path(unicode(input_folder)).glob('**/*.gdb'))
    for gdb in gdbs:
        print(gdb)
except WindowsError, e:
    print("error")
```

The error message that is returned is:

```
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'R:\\Data\\Africa\\Tanzania\\fromDropbox\\DART\\BRT Phase 2-3 designs\\1.12 Engineering Drawings for Service\\ROAD LIGHT\\PDF\\01.Traffic Sign(Kilwa)-??04.pdf'
```

Any help to handle the following error will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with pathlib because of Python 2.7 not being able to handle non-ascii characters. [pathlib chokes up on international characters on Python 2 on Windows](http://bitbucket.org/pitrou/pathlib/issues/25)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
input_folder = r'R:\Data\Africa\Tanzania\fromDropbox\DART\BRT Phase 2-3 designs\1.12 Engineering Drawings for Service\ROAD LIGHT\PDF\01.Traffic Sign(Kilwa)-??04.pdf'
```

The correct call should have 'r' in front of the path, and using single slash.

Comment: as mentioned the path is a raw string so your suggestion doesn't help.